# How to display Date,Month,Year,Hours and minutes in UIDatePicker in Objective C

Tags: uidatepicker

I need to display Date,Month,Year, Hours, Minutes and AM/PM in the same UIDatePicker.As of now when I set the datePickerMode as **UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime** it doesn't display year. I need year to  be displayed with others. Can we do this by any datePicker modes or some other alternatives

This is the code I am using.

```
 self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, screenHeight-264, screenWidth/2, 200)];
                self.datePicker.tag = ansSeq;
                [self.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerChanged:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
                [self.datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime];
                [_dateText setInputView:self.datePicker];
```

Please guide me on this.Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can anyone please post any code to create a custom date picker using UIPickerView.Or a link to a third party code.

Comment: For this question, the most flexible way is to create UIPickerView and add as many components as u need....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46480097/1941338 may help you