# UIDatePicker, display Full Date with YEAR and time

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker, swift4

Can you have a `UIDatePicker` display the day, month, year, and time on the DatePicker, or do I need to make my own custom `UIPickerView`? i.e.

Mon Nov 12 2000 5 20 AM

Currently the date picker with `.datePickerMode` set to `.dateTime` shows

Mon Nov 12 5 20 AM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. But you will need to combine both. Use the picker view for the years and set your date picker minimum to the first day of the selected year and the maximum to the last day of that year. You will need also to  set your `UIDatePicker` property [datePickerMode][1] to `.dateAndTime`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    let years = Array(Date().year-3...Date().year+3)
    var date = Date()
    var lastIndex = 3
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        datePicker.date = Date()
    }
    @IBAction func dateChanged(_ datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
        date = datePicker.date
        print(datePicker.date.year)
        print(datePicker.date)
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        pickerView.selectRow(3, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
        setDatePickerMinimumAndMaximumDatesFor(year: years[3])
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,
                    numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return years.count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return String(years[row])
    }
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func setDatePickerMinimumAndMaximumDatesFor(year: Int) {
        datePicker.minimumDate = year.firstDayOfTheYear
        datePicker.maximumDate = year.lastDayOfTheYear
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
setDatePickerMinimumAndMaximumDatesFor(year: years[row])
        if let optionalDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: (lastIndex > row ? row - lastIndex :  -(lastIndex - row)), to: date) {
            datePicker.date = optionalDate
        }
        print(datePicker.date.year)
        print(datePicker.date)
    }
}
extension Date {
    var year: Int {
        return Calendar.current.component(.year, from: self)
    }
}
extension Int {
    var firstDayOfTheYear: Date {
        return DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: self, month: 1, day: 1).date!
    }
    var lastDayOfTheYear: Date {
        return DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: self, month: 12, day: 31).date!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks, MAN!!! I was halfway into it just saw this and it finishes it up.  Great hack I'm trying to get to that level of coding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155559/discussion-between-jevon718-and-leo-dabus).